# POJO information lost during RPC call (GWT)

Tags: gwt

I am having issues with RPC calls and GWT. Essentially, I have a `Person` class (common code between client and server) that is created in the client side web code, sent to the server code via an RPC call, and then saved to a DB (OrientDB). I have verified that the following work:

1. RPC call - I am able to send info to the server and retrieve info from the server
2. save to DB - have verified that a Person object is saved to the DB

Where I am having issues is the transfer of the POJO from the client to the server. I have verified that the POJO's properties are intact right before it is sent to the server, however, the object passed to the server contains null values for all properties. Essentially, the class is transferred but the information is not. It then saves to the DB, but obviously without any relevant information contained within it.

I will copy what I feel is relevant below, please let me know what else I can provide to make this problem easier to identify. Note these are still in a testing state, so mind the comments :)

Any idea why my POJO's information is being lost in translation?

### `Person` object, followed by the abstract class it inherits from:

```
public class Person extends org.matesweb.shared.AbsPerson implements Serializable
{
    @Id 
    private String id; // DON'T CREATE GETTER/SETTER FOR IT TO PREVENT THE CHANGING BY THE USER APPLICATION, 
                       // UNLESS IT'S NEEDED

    //sets new user details
    public void setPerson(String fIrstName, String mIdInit, String lAstName, String email, String password)
    {
        firstName = fIrstName;
        middleInitial = mIdInit;
        lastName = lAstName;
    }

    /*getter and setter methods - required for every 
     * field due to restrictions imposed by OrientDB*/ 

    public Object getId()
    {
        String tmp;
        tmp = id.toString();
        return tmp;
    }
//end class  
}

public class AbsPerson implements Serializable
{
    String firstName;
    String middleInitial;
    String lastName;

  //  public sys.Login login;

    public org.matesweb.shared.Group[] groups;
    private org.matesweb.shared.Purchase[] purchases;


    /*this method adds a new purchase to the purchases variable*/
/*    public void addPurchase(float price, String description)
    {
        people.Purchase newPurchase = new people.Purchase(login, price, description);
    }
*/    
    /*adds a person to a group by comparing the passed in group ID and PWD*/
    public void addGroup(String groupID, String groupPWD)
    {
        //compare group ID with group PWD to add a user to the group
    }

    /*getter and setter methods - required for every 
     * field due to restrictions imposed by OrientDB*/
    public String getFirstName()
        {
            return firstName;
        }
    public void setFirstName(String name)
        {
            firstName = name;
        }       

    public String getMiddleInitial()
        {
            return middleInitial;
        }
    public void setMiddleInitial(String midInit)
        {
            middleInitial = midInit;
        }       

    public String getLastName()
        {
            return lastName;
        }
    public void setLastName(String ln)
        {
            lastName = ln;
        }       

    /*
    public sys.Login getLogin()
        {
            return login;
        }
    public void setLogin(sys.Login log)
        {
            login = log;
        }
    */

    public org.matesweb.shared.Group[] getGroups()
        {
            return groups;
        }
    public void setGroups(org.matesweb.shared.Group[] gro)
        {
            groups = gro;
        }       

    public org.matesweb.shared.Purchase[] getPurchases()
        {
            return purchases;
        }
    public void setPurchases(org.matesweb.shared.Purchase[] purch)
        {
            purchases = purch;
        }
}
```

### Service

```
package org.matesweb.client;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteService;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteServiceRelativePath;
import org.matesweb.shared.Person;

@RemoteServiceRelativePath("peopleService")
public interface PeopleService extends RemoteService {

//test services
    String stringTest(String outgoingString);
    Person getPerson(String persId);

//production services
    String savePerson(Person p);
}
```

### ServiceAsync

```
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback;
import org.matesweb.shared.Person;

public interface PeopleServiceAsync
{
    //tests
    void stringTest(String outgoingString, AsyncCallback<String> incomingString);
    void getPerson(String persId, AsyncCallback<Person> retPerson);

    //production services
    void savePerson(Person p , AsyncCallback<String> st);
}
```

### `ServiceImpl` call for this particular method:

```
//production calls
    @Override
    public String savePerson(Person p) {
        String st = ioObj.saveObj(p);
        if(st.equals("Success")){
            return "Your information has been saved successfully!";
        } else{
            return "Something has gone wrong on our end... Sorry! Error:<br /> " + st;
        } 
    }
```

and finally, the call itself

```
private static void savePerson(Person p)
    {        
        // Initialize the service proxy.
        if (peopleSvc == null) {
          peopleSvc = GWT.create(PeopleService.class);
        }

        //resets status
        st="";

        // Set up the callback object.
        AsyncCallback<String> callback = new AsyncCallback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                st = caught.getMessage();
                Label stLabel= new Label(st);
                personTable.setWidget(3,1,stLabel);            
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String result) {
                st = result;
                HTML stLabel= new HTML(st);
                joinPanel.add(stLabel);
            }
        };
        // Make the call to the people service.
        peopleSvc.savePerson(p, callback);    
    }
```

Comment: Can you try again by adding default constructor to your pojo?

Comment: Ignore the above comment. I misread the Person class. I deleted the reference in the answer too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by implementing GWT's IsSerializable interface. I also removed the Serializable interface from the Person class and let it inherit IsSerializable from the abstract class it inherits from.